# how to configure search that results the content within any document created/uploaded in sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online

Basically, we can search for document names in the search box but i want to get the search results also for the content inside the documents in sharepoint online site.can anyone help me out in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default we can search the content inside the documents in sharepoint online. You need to wait until the document is crawled.

Default crawled file name extensions and parsed file types in SharePoint for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-crawled-file-name-extensions-and-parsed-file-types

Comment: Yes, it is displaying search results but it is not highlighting the text in the document? Is there any way to do that?